# syntax for setting output_buffering in .htaccess? (php 5)

Tags: .htaccess, output-buffering

What is the syntax for setting output_buffering to off in .htaccess?

Provide a complete .htaccess file content please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is isn't really a hard thing to find. Anyway, you need to make sure you have PHP running as an apache module for this to work in `.htaccess`.

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value output_buffering Off
</IfModule>
```