# dompdf creates defective pdf on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I want to create a pdf on my wordpress homepage with dompdf. Local an my computer with xampp there is no problem, all works fine.
On wordpress I am using the plugin "PHP Code For Posts". The dompdf folder I copied to the folder of the plugin.
The pdf get created but it is defective.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

    function pdf_create($filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE)  
    {
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
        $dompdf->load_html('TEST');
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    }

    $filename = 'file_name';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    pdf_create($filename, 'A4', 'portait');  
}

?>

<form method="post" >
    <p>Test: <input type="text" name="price" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="button" value="PDF" /></p> 
</form>
```

I hope anybody can help me. I have no idea why it works local and on wordpress it creates a defective file.

UPDATE:

Here is the code when I open the defective file with notepad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de-DE">

<head>


<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<link rel="pingback" href="http://test-homepage.de/xmlrpc.php">


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://test-homepage.de/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/js/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test-homepage.de/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/css/ie.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<title>Test &#8211; test-homepage</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="test-homepage &raquo; Feed" href="http://test-homepage.de/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/test-homepage.de\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3"}};
```

Comment: Download the PDF file and open it in notepad or a similar program. Examine the header of the document, in most cases you will find a PHP error or warning message that scrambles the PDF header. Also check the file size, in case it is 0KB, an error prevented the DOMPDF lib to save the document in a temporary folder prior to streaming it to the client.

Comment: At first the file has not 0 KB. And also with notepad I can not find any error. I added the code out of notepad to my question above.

Comment: _“On wordpress I am using the plugin "PHP Code For Posts"”_ – that might be part of the problem … Most likely that plugin is designed to insert short snippets of PHP code (resp. their output) into rendered post content – but it will rather not prevent that the whole template “around” it will get rendered, so that in the end you still end up with a full HTML document, and that is not a valid PDF. Since it doesn’t look like you are using any WP functionality in the code(?), it might be easier to just call it as a stand-alone script.

Comment: As Cbroe mentioned, a plugin normally only adds functionality to Wordpress and in most instances it will  be loaded as part of the Wordpress layout and thus will include the HTML from your template. Depending on your php.ini setting there may be a hack available; I'll add an example as an answer to show how this works.

Comment: I am using this plugin because of the shortcode. I want to create a woocommerce catalogue and instead of a 'add to cart' button I want a button for creating a pdf. The products for this catalogue I am importing from a csv file. My csv importing plugin has one fix saved template, where I can add the php shortcode. So I can be sure that I have always the pdf creating button on all product pages. Maybe there would be a more elegant way, but I did not learn php and so it is all quite new and difficult for me.

Comment: So far, has the problem be solved? I have encountered this issue as well.PDF is rendered the wrong HTML is like take the buffer data even use ob_clean().

Answer (score 1):

This may be a solution if you want to stick to the currently used Wordpress plugin and output buffering is enabled (both webserver and php.ini may control output buffering; see the [output buffering section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) on the PHP.net page for more details.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    // make sure that output buffering has been enabled
    if (ob_start()) {
        // clear previous contents from the server output cache
        ob_clean();
        try {
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
            spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

            $filename = 'file_name';
            $paper= 'A4';
            $orientation= 'portrait';

            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
            $dompdf->load_html('TEST');
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");

            // make sure the content of the buffer is sent to the client.
            ob_flush();
            // terminate the script to make sure no additional content is sent.
            exit(0);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            error_log(sprintf("PDF generation failed with %s in line %d", $ex->getMessage(), $ex->getLine()));
        }
    } else {
        // log a message in default error log
        error_log("Output buffering could not be enabled (PDF routine)");
    }
}

?>
```

---

### Debugging your setup

As you said you are pretty new to PHP, please create a file with the content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Upload the file to your server and open the file with your browser, scroll down until you find "Configuration" > "PHP Core". In the list below, search for the entry "output_buffering". If it is set to "0", output buffering has been disabled via php.ini. If it has been disabled, all output of your page is directly send to the client and there is no programmatic way to do what you achieve without changing the server setup.

[image]

There may be several ways to enable buffering, i.e. your provider may allow changing certain settings via web configuration software or you may add an `.htaccess` file to your web directory to enable it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561829/syntax-for-setting-output-buffering-in-htaccess-php-5).

---

### Another update

As you already found out, output buffering has been enabled properly, so we should be able to modify the output buffer to create the PDF even if output had been served before. I copied your code, ran the PHP part after some output had already been sent to the browser and the same happened as on your web page, the static HTML content was also included in my PDF document. The main problem will be that Wordpress does not use output buffering internally and sends the output directly to the browser.

Here's what I did that resolved the problem -> start the output buffering as soon as possible, inside your index.php:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

After buffering had been enabled, I was able to control the buffer and generate the PDF file as required.

---

### Further diagnosis

I just want to make sure we are not missing something, could you add this to your PDF generation code:

```
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
  $sent = headers_sent($file, $line);
  die("The output started in {$file} and at line {$line}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get the same result as before. The pdf is also defective and the code in notepad is actually the same as I have posted above.

Comment: I don't know if error logging is enabled on your server and if you have access to your log file directory but I assume that you can't access it directly when not self-hosted. Exchange the above `error_log` entries with `die` statements and see if one of the statements is reached. It could be a path (i.e. DOMPDF not available) or as mentioned before a permissions issue.

Comment: I think the path is right because if I change it with a wrong path I get an error on my homepage and no pdf will be create. I changed the error_log function with the die function, but I do not get any statements, how should I reach this statements?

Comment: I updated my above answer and added some debugging steps that you need to perform. Let us know what you find!

Comment: Thanks again. I can't change the php.ini but I added now php_value output_buffering On to the .htcaccess file. Local value for output_buffering is now on but the master value for output_buffering has still no value. I don't know how to change the master value. With this setup the created pdf file is still defective.

Comment: @DocBrown you can't change the master value as this is defined by the php.ini setting. Could you add the `phpinfo();` and `die();` calls to your PHP snippet before the `new DOMPDF();` row and check if that also says that output_buffering is on?

Comment: I added it to my php code and yes, the local value of output_buffering is also on.

Comment: it still does not work. can you exclude that output_buffering is the problem because when I add to the dompdf code phpinfo(); the local value of output_buffering says on? Could it be an other problem?

Comment: @DocBrown I had some time to set up a demo on my machine and found a solution that worked on my machine. The the *Another update* section of my answer above and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I don't get it running. Currently I have add `php_value output_buffering On` to the .htcaccess and `ob_start();` to the index.php. For creating the pdf I use your php code, that you have posted above. Unfortunately, I only know the real basics about php...

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your Wordpress setup, otherwise it would work by now. You added the `ob_start();` to Wordpress' index.php, right? Could you try and switch the WP template to one of the templates included with the default installation?

Comment: Another idea: what is the phpinfo() setting for `implicit_flush`?

Comment: yes ob_start is in the index.php. Switching the template helped nothing. And implicit_flush is off. Switching it on helped also nothing.

Comment: I think without live debugging possibility there's hardly a chance to find the error. I added another debugging attempt to my answer above, please give it a try.

Comment: I don't know if I included the code correctly but I get "The output started in and at line 0"

Comment: Which means that no output has been sent to the browser yet which under normal circumstances means that the rest of your code should work. If you exchange the `headers_sent();` with a `die();` statement, is anything shown in the browser's HTML source?

Comment: Do you mean to exchange `$sent = headers_sent($file, $line);` with `$sent = die($file, $line);`? So I get the following error for that line as soon as I press the button: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /www/htdocs/.../.../wp-content/plugins/php-code-for-posts/Classes/Shortcode.php(81) : eval()'d code on line 22"

Comment: No, no, just a plain `die();` without parameters and return values.

Comment: @BrianS that's exactly what I recommended in my answer you just commented ;-)

Comment: @SaschaM78 so you did, how embarrassing

Comment: @SaschaM78 Do you mean like that `$sent = die();` and without
  `die("The output started in {$file} and at line {$line}");`? Then I get a nearly empty white page with only some parts of my theme.

Comment: @SaschaM78 You wrote "Which means that no output has been sent to the browser yet". I already said that I am amateur, but where could be the problem. Which settings could be wrong, the settings of php, wordpress or even of dompdf? There should be a possibility anyway to delimit the options.

Comment: Let's continue our discussion [in this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123266/room-for-docbrown-and-sascham78)

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Unfortunately I get the message "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"